# Announcement: New policy on homework questions

Tags: discussion

A proposal by FooBar on the handling of homework questions (see [An alternative suggestion regarding Homework Questions](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/an-alternative-suggestion-regarding-homework-questions)) has received significant support from the community and no dissenting votes. Details of the proposal can be found at the above link.

Since the voice of the community has spoken, I suggest that—unless any dissenters make themselves immediately known—we now accept the linked proposal as a part of our policy for dealing with homework questions, begin enforcing this policy, and modify [Welcome to Economics.SE!](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164/welcome-to-economics-se) accordingly.

Comment: just_do_it_shia_lebeouf.jpgif

Comment: Let's do it....

Comment: I just looked at the examples given in the homework policy page: http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions and concluded that if I were to see the "great question" posted on econ.se I would not find it great at all. In particular, it does not give a solution attempt. From the wording of the policy it seems that this may just be a great example of the second point, but this is somewhat unclear. Do we need to edit this?

Comment: @HRSE Good point: do you have any suggestions? An alternative approach would be to simply delete the examples.

Comment: I think the two bullet points do not require clarification. However, we could include a list of "great homework questions" where we give links to actual questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done the following:

- Created [Economics.SE Policy on Homework Questions](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions)
- Edited [Welcome to Economics.SE!](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164/welcome-to-economics-se) to point to [Economics.SE Policy on Homework Questions](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions)
- Updated https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to reflect these changes.

Both pages are Community Wikis, so everyone should feel free to help maintaining them.

Comment: What about the suggestion for  http://economics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask  ? It is at least as likely that newcomers will visit this Help question than the "on-topic" Help question.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Unfortunately, we don't seem to be able to edit the content of that page.

Answer (score 6):

In the "Welcome" meta-post, but also in the Help question "What topics can I ask about here?", https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, as we have done already with the rest of the site-specific guidance.

I would also suggest to put our full site-specific guidance in another Help question, https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask  which appears first in the Help list under the title "What types of questions should I avoid asking?"

In my opinion it is totally unproductive that these two Help questions exist separately, but since this is SE-wide, I guess, and can't be changed, let's fill each with the same site-specific information.

A note: @Foobar offered a specific suggested text in an answer to his own proposal. Per previous discussions, the suggested text appears wordy, *but* the problem of homework/self study questions is so twisted that I believe demands a bit more explanation and guidance.

Finally: regarding "numerical content", let's be careful with questions that relate to simulations and/or Econometrics. These questions may present a case with specific data and specific numerical results / troubles, but in order to address them one has to go down to structure, so I think they should get a pass. For example somebody may not understand why a specific data set is giving him the estimation results it does, and pastes in his question all the relevant information: the answer will usually lie in wrong model specification or wrong software use, rather than arithmetic operations, and so it will be generally useful. Perhaps we should add something to @Foobar's suggested text on the matter.

Comment: +1 for that final part

Answer (score -1):

I would be careful with this.  I have asked conceptual questions and used arbitrary numbers to illustrate this but was wrongly accused of asking a homework question.

I suggestion not censoring "homework questions" as the moderator is not psychic and can and will censor legit questions.

The number suggestion is flawed for a number of reasons.  First many visitors aren't lawyers in stackexchange by-laws and will unwittingly ask a question with numbers and it will get censured and they will be upset.

I suggest flipping the dynamics around.  Leave it up to the public to determine what is a homework question.  If they think it is, they can still answer it using conceptual helpful explanations without being a human calculator.

Comment: This question is a perfect example. It is hard to say if this is homework or not, and it might sometimes scare new users away if we have such a strict policy on homework. I'm thinking of this topic: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/18561/moral-hazard-or-free-riding