# Proposal for Custom Off-Topic Close Reason

Tags: feature-request, homework

I have created a proposal for a new option for closing homework questions that don't meet the standards that we've set forth. I anticipate the benefit of this being that the reason for closing will be a little more clear for new-comers posting homework questions. Also, there will be less work involved in closing a question because you wont have to write a comment describing the reason every time you vote to close a homework question.

When you choose to close a question, there is an option to edit reasons.

[image]

I clicked this and proposed the following reason as a new option:

> This question does not meet the standards for homework questions as
>   spelled out in the relevant meta posts. For more information, see
>   [here](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1458/announcement-new-policy-on-homework-questions?cb=1)
>   and [here](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24/how-should-we-deal-with-homework-questions)
>   .

I'd like to get some feedback on if you think this should be a new option and if it needs any re-wording. When/if we decide on it, it needs another moderator to approve it. The link to approve it can be found here: https://economics.stackexchange.com/admin/flags/close-as-off-topic

Comment: There seems to be a tpyo in the new option: question -> questions

Comment: Fixed it. Tahnks! :)

Comment: Seems like a good feature to add.~

Comment: I just saw this. I can't believe I missed it earlier. +100000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 13 November 2015:**

I have now approved this and we should be able to start applying the new close reason.

---

**Original post**

Thanks, I didn't realise that we had the capacity to add such reasons. I think we should definitely ratify this, and will gladly approve it! But first I wondered if it might be better to construct a canonical FAQ for homework questions and link to that, rather than linking to meta discussion pages where people may encounter conflicting (and thus confusing) opinions.

I took the libery of editing the proposal along the lines that I had in mind

> This question does not meet the standards for homework questions as spelled out in the relevant meta posts. For more information, see [our policy on homework question](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions) and [the general FAQ](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Let me know if you think this is okay and I will "approve" it.

Comment: Cool. I agree. Thanks for setting that up. Looks good to me so far. As soon as we get some more votes, let's go ahead and confirm it.