# Answering Homework Questions

Tags: discussion

This question is prompted by seeing [this question and answer](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/13666/optimal-consumtion-bundle-of-lemons-and-sugar).  The question is fairly obviously homework, but doesn't meet our [policy on homework questions](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions).  Four people, to date, have voted for it to be closed, giving the OP an opportunity to edit it to comply with the policy. To that extent the 'system' is working.

In the meantime, however, a detailed answer has been posted, one going well beyond hints or the 'broad perspective' suggested in our policy (in the answer by Fix B).  The answer has already been accepted, which makes it rather unlikely that the OP is going to edit the question to meet the policy.

Question: Should we give clearer and more accessible guidance on answering homework questions, including a link from 'How do I write a good answer?' in the Help Centre?

Addendum: I've added alternative answers so that the meaning of any votes will be clear.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the guidance on answering homework questions should be made clearer and/or more accessible.

Comment: It is worth a shot. However I think there will always be people who will have not read the guidance or will have done so but will disagree with it.

Answer (score 0):

No, the existing guidance on answering homework questions is adequate.