# Qualification to Vote to Close a Question

Tags: support, bug

On seeing [this question](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1662/should-i-downvote-valid-answers-to-off-topic-questions), a point that occurred to me is that on this site it sometimes takes a while (from memory up to a day or so) for off-topic questions to be closed. If such questions were closed more quickly, this might reduce the frequency of answers to off-topic questions.  This led me to check how many participants are able to vote to close questions, and I am puzzled by what I found.

The [Privileges](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) page in the Help Centre says that it needs 500+ rep.  This would include about 100 people.  But when voting myself to close a question, I have noticed an indicator that seems to be counting the possible voters down from 25 (ie if one person has already voted it will show 24 votes remaining). Is there a reason for this apparent discrepancy, or is it an error?

Comment: This question made me look at the [Close Vote statistics](http://economics.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats) and they are scary. Top 8 reviewers make up 62% of the votes. I have never seen the top reviewer cast a vote that was not 'Leave Open' so I guess her 11% of votes should not be counted when we are looking at how fast off-topic questions could be closed. There are 79 people eligible to vote. Where are you guys...?

Comment: Btw Adam I don't see any of your votes in recent history...

Comment: @denesp  I've actually cast 5 close votes since 14 Jan (eg here (http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/15120/help-please-i-cant-work-out-this-equation)), but as has been my habit I did this via 'Close' under each question, not via the Review queue.  When I went to the Close Vote Statistics under Review, it showed my all time score as zero, so it looks as if these stats only count votes cast via the Review queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that counter just means you can have a maximum of 25 close votes simoultaneously. After registering a close vote try to see where the counter starts from on another random question. (You don't really have to vote to close it.) The counter for me is currently at 23.

Comment: Yes, I can  see it now, here (http://economics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)